# wcscmp arguments randomly just stopped working?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using this:

```
const wchar_t TARGET_NAME[] = L"ac_client.exe";
if (!wcscmp(pe32.szExeFile, TARGET_NAME))
```

to find a process and compare names to match them, pe32 being a PROCESSENTRY32. It used to work, but randomly it just stopped for no reason. It now does the red underline under pe32, saying "argument of type "CHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const wchar_t *""

I don't really understand. Is there anything else with this? I even did

```
#include <wchar.h>
```

just in case.

Comment: Did you remove or undefine the `UNICODE` macro?

Comment: You should make sure your project is configured to use Unicode character set

Comment: Ah, yes. I had to add _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS and didn't realize I replaced all defaults.

Comment: Did not happen randomly. Look in your revision control system to see what you changed.

Answer (score 1):

As documented, the [PROCESSENTRY32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839.aspx) structure either expands to `PROCESSENTRY32W`, if `UNICODE` is defined, or `PROCESSENTRY32A` otherwise. *You* changed the preprocessor symbols. The error doesn't just pop up *"randomly"*. If you want your code to compile irrespective of the compiler environment, explicitly use the Unicode names (`PROCESSENTRY32W` and `Process32FirstW`).